# YouTube Playlist as Gallery View

Tags: html, joomla, youtube-api

I want to embed a YouTube Playlist that shows the videos in the list as thumbnails and a big frame with the current video. I am working with Joomla! 2.5 and I want to embed that into an article as HTML or if someone can recommend an extension or another way to do that.

Thank you very much, I am kind of new developing websites.

Comment: maybe people expect you to look in the Joomla Extensions Directory as the solution to your request is using a component. However I remember when I first started using Joomla and had didn't know where to look. Hope my answer below helped and will boost you up a vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-media/video-channels/13075

If not, there are more extensions that can be found [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-media/video-channels)